# How to track the most recent modification in a sql record?

Tags: sql-server

I have a table to track the Student details and there is another table to track the performance of the student.

```
+==========================================+
| ID      |  Department     | Date         |
+==========================================+
| 001     | English         | Jan 3 2017   |
| 001     | English         | Feb 24 2017  |
| 001     | Science         | Mar 1 2017   |
| 001     | Maths           | Mar 2 2017   |
| 001     | Maths           | Mar 21 2017  |
| 001     | Maths           | Apr 2 2017   |
| 001     | English         | Apr 7 2017   |
| 002     | Maths           | Feb 1 2017   |
| 002     | Maths           | Apr 7 2017   |
| 003     | Maths           | Apr 3 2017   |
| 003     | Maths           | Apr 7 2017   |
| 004     | Science         | Feb 1 2017   |
| 004     | Science         | Mar 1 2017   |
| 004     | Maths           | Apr 7 2017   |
| 004     | English         | Apr 9 2017   |
+==========================================+
```

Performance table:

```
+===========================================================================+
| ID      |  Department         | Best score|  Avg score    |   Date        |
+===========================================================================+
| 001     | English             |   98      |   85          | Jan 30 2017   |
| 001     | English             |   89      |   80.2        | Apr 14 2017   |
| 001     | Science             |   75      |   79.8        | May 1 2017    |
| 001     | Maths               |   88      |   80.2        | Jan 12 2017   |
| 001     | Maths               |   79      |   75.6        | Feb 21 2017   |
| 001     | Maths               |   90      |   80.5        | Jan 20 2017   |
| 001     | English             |   80      |   79.3        | Mar 27 2017   |
| 002     | Maths               |   90      |   78.4        | Mar 31 2017   |
| 002     | Maths               |   85      |   80.2        | May 7 2017    |
| 003     | Maths               |   75      |   79.1        | Apr 30 2017   |
| 003     | Maths               |   80      |   80.0        | Feb 7 2017    |
| 004     | Science             |   60      |   70.3        | May 1 2017    |
| 004     | Science             |   72      |   69.9        | Mar 10 2017   |
| 004     | Maths               |   70      |   66.8        | Jan 17 2017   |
| 004     | English             |   65      |   65.0        | Mar 29 2017   |
+===========================================================================+
```

I want to get the most recent performance and average score of the student whenever a department change happens in the student table. Considering student 001, the student's dept changes are

```
| 001     | English         | Jan 3 2017   |
| 001     | Science         | Mar 1 2017   |
| 001     | Maths           | Apr 2 2017   |
```

For,
Jan 3 2017, There is no date that is less than the date in the Performance table.

Mar 1 2017, The most recent record in performance table is of date Feb 21 2017

Apr 2 2017, The most recent record in performance table is of date Mar 27 2017

Please help me in doing it.

Comment: output is not at all clear.Can you reexplain the output ?Why first row output is so and why second row onwards ?

Comment: Please post the SQL query you used to get that output?

Comment: @KumarHarsh: Considering the Student 001 dept changes he has 3 records. If I take the date, Jan 3 2017 and compare it in performance table, there is no record that is less than that date in performance table. For Mar 1 2017, there are 4 records Jan 30, Jan 12, Feb 21 and jan 20. But the most recent date is Feb 21.

Comment: question is not very clear

Comment: @CleanBold Can you please let me know which part of the question is not clear?

Comment: @JayF1 I used the query below to get the department changes. I need a query to get the performance tracking records for those dates
;WITH temps AS 
(
   SELECT sd.*, LEAD(sd.Department, 1) OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY sd.[Date])  AS NextDepartment
   FROM table sd    
)
SELECT t.id, t.Department,t.[Date] FROM temps t
WHERE t.Department != t.NextDepartment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a little pain to explain clearly if my script is wrong

Hope the output that you have explain is correct.Becasue i hv lil doubts about the output.

Most importantly hope you have posted exactly same table structure .

Because of your table structure,lil more window function is use than expected,which may hamper your performance.

It is all together very different and important discussion about your real requirement and what should be table structure and how it should be populated.

Try this script with various sample data and let me know,

```
declare @StudentDetails table(ID varchar(20)
,Department varchar(20),Dates Date)
insert into @StudentDetails VALUES
('001','English','Jan 3 2017 ') 
,('001','English','Feb 24 2017') 
,('001','Science','Mar 1 2017 ') 
,('001','Maths','Mar 2 2017 ') 
,('001','Maths','Mar 21 2017') 
,('001','Maths','Apr 2 2017 ') 
,('001','English','Apr 7 2017 ') 
,('002','Maths','Feb 1 2017 ') 
,('002','Maths','Apr 7 2017 ') 
,('003','Maths','Apr 3 2017 ') 
,('003','Maths','Apr 7 2017 ') 
,('004','Science','Feb 1 2017 ') 
,('004','Science','Mar 1 2017 ') 
,('004','Maths','Apr 7 2017 ') 
,('004','English','Apr 9 2017 ') 
--select * from @StudentDetails

declare @Performance table( ID varchar(20)
,Department varchar(20),Bestscore float,Avgscore float,PDate date)

insert into @Performance VALUES
 ('001','English',98,85    ,'Jan 30 2017')
,('001','English',89,80.2  ,'Apr 14 2017')
,('001','Science',75,79.8  ,'May 1 2017 ')
,('001','Maths',88,80.2  ,'Jan 12 2017')
,('001','Maths',79,75.6  ,'Feb 21 2017')
,('001','Maths',90,80.5  ,'Jan 20 2017')
,('001','English',80,79.3  ,'Mar 27 2017')
,('002','Maths',90,78.4  ,'Mar 31 2017')
,('002','Maths',85,80.2  ,'May 7 2017 ')
,('003','Maths',75,79.1  ,'Apr 30 2017')
,('003','Maths',80,80.0  ,'Feb 7 2017 ')
,('004','Science',60,70.3  ,'May 1 2017 ')
,('004','Science',72,69.9  ,'Mar 10 2017')
,('004','Maths',70,66.8  ,'Jan 17 2017')
,('004','English',65,65.0  ,'Mar 29 2017')
--select * from @Performance
--declare @SID  varchar(20)='001'

;with CTE as
(
select *
,ROW_NUMBER()over(partition by id order by Dates,Department) rn
from @StudentDetails
--where id=@SID
)
,CTE3 AS(
select c.id, c.Department,c.dates,c.rn,1 rn3
from cte c
where rn=1

union ALL

select c.id, c.Department,c.dates,c.rn
,case when c.Department=c3.Department  and c.dates>c3.dates 
then cast(c3.rn3 as int)
else cast(c3.rn3+1 as int) end
from cte c
inner join cte3 c3
on c.id=c3.id
where c.rn=c3.rn+1
and c.rn<=7
)
,cte4 AS(
select *,0 rn1 from cte3 where rn=1
union ALL
select * from 
(
select * ,ROW_NUMBER()over(PARTITION by id,rn3 order by dates desc) rn1
from cte3
where rn3>1
)t4 where t4.rn1=1
)

select c.id,c.department,c.dates,fn.Avgscore AVGScroe,fn.pdate RecentPDate 
from cte4 c
OUTER apply(
select * from
(select p.*,ROW_NUMBER()over( order by pdate desc)rn2 
from @Performance P
where c.id=p.id and p.pDate<c.dates)t4
where rn2=1 )fn
order by c.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this...

```
SELECT S.ID,S.DATE,MAX(P.AVG_SCORE),MAX(P.BEST_SCORE)
FROM STUDENT S, PERFORMANCE P
WHERE P.DATE < S.DATE AND P.ID = S.ID
GROUP BY S.ID,S.DATE
```

Thanks..